# How to "tag" images

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have got 3 tables: images table: this has my pictures with their id (PK), names, blob, description etc

Second table: tags table: this has tag id (PK), tag name

Third table: this is aims to connect the two tables: id (PK), image id (FK) which relates to the image table, tag id (FK) which relates to the tags table.

I want to have an image to have many tags that the user can select from the drop down select box. How can I can enable the user to tag the image so that the image can have multiple tags

I am using PHP and MYSQL. For example the tags that appear when posting a question on stack overflows however, mine will be for images.

Comment: @Hammad at there is no code but I want a general idea of how this can be done. Have you got an example of what I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of pseudocode to get you started. The values in HTML are the PK for tags and the image.

```
<select name="tags[]" multiple>
    <option value="1">Cool</option>
    <option value="2">Gross</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="image_id" />

foreach($_POST['tags'] as $tag)
{
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO table3 (image_id, tag_id) VALUES(' . $_POST['image_id'] . ', ' . $tag . ')';
    $pdo->execute($sql);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I will try working off this tonight. If I have any further questions is it okay to ask you tomorrow?

Comment: Sure thing :)! I think you should be able to get my email address of my profile page, you can email me directly as well. Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if you are satisfied with the answer :).

Answer (score 0):

Create two tables named: tags and image_tags  in your database design. Tags table would contain all the available tags and image_tags table would contain id of image and id of tag. Thats it.

As far as front view is concerned you can use input tokenizer plugin by james smith: http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

Comment: Thanks for this, I will take a look into this and get back to you